# Core Java Practical Questions

Tags: java

A Test array has the following property:

```
a[0] = a[1] + a[2] = a[3] + a[4] + a[5] = a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] = ...
```

The length of a Test array must be n*(n+1)/2 for some n.

Write a method named isTestArray that returns 1 if its array argument is a Test array, otherwise it returns 0. The function signature is:

```
int isMadhavArray(int[ ] a)
```

**Example:**

[image]

**This is what I have tried:**

```
public class TestArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(isTestArray(new int[] {2,1,1,4,-1,-1}));
}

static int isTestArray(int[] a){

    boolean isEq=true;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        int n=i, value=a.length;
        int equation=n*(n+1)/2;
        if(value==equation)
        {
            for(int x=0,y=1;y<a.length;x++,y++){
                if(a[0]==a[x]+a[y]){
                    //having problem over here :(
                }
            }
        }
        else
            isEq=false;
    }
    if(isEq)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: The problem is I couldn't solve it! :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt for your troubling inner for loop. Because each time you loop, you increment the number of indexes you need to add by one, so I think you need another nested loop like this. I know it is ugly. Can't blame me, I am a beginner.

```
public class TestArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isTestArray(new int[] {2,1,1,4,-1,-1}));
}

static int isTestArray(int[] a) {
    boolean isEq = false;
    for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int n=i, value = a.length;
        int equation= n*(n+1)/2;
        if (value==equation) {
            int index = 1;
            for (int x = 1; x < a.length; x++) {
                int total = 0;
                for (int y = index, count = 0; count < x+1; y++, count++) {
                    if (y!= a.length) {
                        total += a[y];
                        if (total == a[0])
                            isEq = true;
                        else
                            isEq = false;
                        index++;

                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isEq)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dummy! For your response. But every time the inner for loop runs, the value of index is started with 1, right??? So the array property doesn't match here. After checking a0 =a1+a2 the next iteration should check if a0=a3+a4+a5. And this goes on. Could you please check this.

Comment: Guys!!! This question is from online practical test  for admission to MUM university. I find the questions bit confusing. So if you have solutions for past year questions for the test, please inform me. I will really appreciate your contribution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it starts at 1, because you are not using the index 0 for the addition. Run it, and you will see. I tested it, and it gave me the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Number of elements in sum increases by 1 in every portion.

You should do 2 things:

1. Write a method that will calculate sum of N elements starting from K position in array
2. Increment `i` with the number of the smallest portion in iteration

example code:

```
int portionSize = 1; // number of elements to sum
int position = 0; // index of first element

while (position + 2 * portionSize + 1 < array.length) { // condition for last iteration
    if (sum(position, portionSize) != sum(position + portionSize, portionSize + 1) {
        return false; // if not equal, return immediately
   }
   position += portionSize;
   portionSize++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks AdamSkywalker for your response. But I find your solution doesn't fulfill the property of the array. a0=a1+a2=a3+a4+a5... Every time an array element is being added. Could you please check this. Thanks

Comment: @Keith I don't understand: this code does exactly this check - it checks if a0 = a1 + a2, then it checks if a1+a2 = a3+a4+a5 and so on

Comment: Actually, it returns 1 if the array elements fulfills the property of the TestArray. Eg. a[0] should be equal to a[1]+a[2] , should be equal to a[3]+a[4]+a[5]. similarly, every time an array is added and it should be equal to a[0]

Comment: @Keith the task was to write a single method and now you talk about adding new elements

Comment: you misunderstood me. The property of the array is like that. I have already mentioned it in question, above. I mean to say, in codes, in every loop one additional element is to be added then before, according to the TestArray property.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays:**

```
int liste1[]= new int[] {2, 1 ,1};
int liste2[]= new int[] {2, 1, 1, 4, -1, -1};
int liste3[]= new int[] {6, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0};
int liste4[]= new int[] {18, 9, 10, 6, 6, 6};
int liste5[]= new int[] {-6, -3, -3, 8, -5, -4};        
int liste6[]= new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -2, -1};
int liste7[]= new int[] {3, 1, 2, 3, 0};
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
public static boolean isMadhavArray(int a[]) {
int position = 1; 
int count_size = 2;
int sum = 0;
System.out.printf("a.length= %s \n", a.length);
while ( (position + count_size) <= a.length ) {
    for (int i=position; i < (position + count_size) ;i++) {
            sum += a[i];
    }
    if ( a[0] == sum ) {            
        System.out.printf("Count_size is %s started at position %s \n", count_size, position);
        System.out.printf("Sum is %s \n", sum);
        // move to next position from the previous count_size
        position = position + count_size;
        count_size +=1;             
        //reset sum to zero
        sum = 0;
    }else { //return false if ever a sum not equal to the first item of the array
        System.out.printf("Sum is %s \n", sum);
        return false;
    }       
};
return position < a.length && position + count_size > a.length ? false : true;}
```

Comment: The function works fine for all test cases below

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(isTestArray(new int[] {2,1,1}));
        System.out.println(isTestArray(new int[] {3, 1, 2, 3, 0}));
    }

    static int isTestArray(int[] a){

        boolean isEq=false, isEx=false;
        int equation=0,value=a.length;
    //for equation check        
        for(int n=0;n<value;n++){
            equation=n*(n+1)/2;
            if(value==equation){
                isEx=true;
                break;
            }
        }   
    //if equation is true       
        if(isEx)
        {
            int x=1,y=3,c=0,sum=0;
            do{
                for(int I=x,J=y;I<J;I++){
                    sum=sum+a[I];
                }
                if(a[0]==sum){
                    isEq=true;
                    sum=0;
                }
                else{
                    isEq=false;
                    break;
                }                       
                c++;
                x=y;
                y=x+2+c;
            }while(x<a.length);
        }
    //last operation of return  
        if(isEq)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

    }
   }
```

Comment: This code also works fine!!! Dummy's answer is also correct. One can use any of the codes as answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;

public class StackQues1{
    static boolean flag = true;
    static int arrLength = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Console c = System.console();   
        System.out.println("Enter the length of array - ");
        arrLength = Integer.parseInt(c.readLine());

        //Let max val of n<=20
        //To check n(n+1)/2
        boolean nFlag = false;
        for(int n=1;n<=20;n++){
            if(arrLength == (n*(n+1))/2){
            nFlag = true;
            }
        }       
        if(!nFlag){
            System.out.println("Length of array is not in the form of (n*(n+1))/2");
        }else{      
            int arr[] = new int[arrLength];         
            System.out.println("Enter the elements of array - ");
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(c.readLine());
            }

            System.out.println("Returned value = "+isTestArray(arr));
        }
    }

    //Logic Implementation
    public static int isTestArray(int[] arr){       
            int sum = 0;        
            int noOfElements=0;
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;){
                noOfElements++;
                sum=0;
                for(int j=1;j<=noOfElements;j++){
                    sum=sum+arr[i];
                    i++;
                }
                if(arr[0] == sum){
                    flag = true;
                }else{
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
```